# What is a good way to suppress exceptions inside the rescue clause in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling, rescue

```
begin
  do_something
rescue
  Logger.write ...

  ...error handling...
end
```

The problem is that it is possible that the code ***inside the rescue*** raises an exception. For this use case, I want to suppress it.

So, how to wrap the rescue in a rescue to suppress the Exception?

Comment: you can use an other `begin rescue` block inside the rescue. Or just do nothing in the rescue block.
I'm not sure to understand what is your problem. If the code raise an exception on your `rescue` block, I want to say you: just fix the bug :)

Answer (score 5):

You said it yourself

> wrap the rescue in a rescue

*Exception Inception*

There's no special way other than wrapping blocks of code in a `begin rescue end` block:

```
begin
  do_something
rescue
  begin
    Logger.write ...
  rescue
    ...error handling...
  end
end
```

...unless you're using ActiveSupport: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-suppress

```
suppress(Exception) do
  # all exceptions will be suppressed
end
```

..but it isn't a plain Ruby thing and I noticed you didn't add a rails tag to your question. Though, you can implement `suppress` yourself. Or, just, here take this:

```
def suppress(*exception_classes)
  yield
rescue *exception_classes
end
```

Use that in your rescue:

```
begin
  do_something
rescue
  Logger.write ...

  suppress Exception do
    ...error handling...
  end
end
```

In plain old Ruby it's got to be rescues all the way down (and indeed, `suppress` is just a nested rescue) but let me just state that it's a bad idea to rescue all exceptions, in essence, by not being explicit about what exception you're rescuing, in other words, by not passing an exception class argument to `rescue` you're implicitly rescuing `StandardError` which is the superclass to most exceptions ([more info here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html)). This can lead to hard to find bugs.

```
begin    
rescue
end
```

..is the same as:

```
begin
rescue StandardError
end
```

It's much better to know what exception you're rescuing and be explicit about it:

```
begin
rescue SomeApiError => e
  # do something when this specific exception occurs
end
```

With that figured out you can use a cascade strategy to rescue your exceptions:

```
begin
  # do the thing
rescue SomeApiError => e 
  # specific rescue
rescue SomeOtherError => e
  # more broad error handling
rescue
  # catch all rescue
end
```

With the above only the rescue clause that matches the exception being raised will run however, code in a rescue block won't be rescued by subsequent rescues, only the code in the `begin` block is rescuable.

If you want to have a block of code that always runs even in the event of an exception, use the `ensure` keyword:

```
begin
  # code
rescue => e
  # rescue code
ensure
  # this block will always run exception or not
end
```

Comment: `rescue` is not same as `rescue Exception`.